# How would i apply inheritance to very similar classes, like BlueScrollBar and RedScrollBar?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, processing

i'm a beginner to inheritance in programming, i'm trying to desgin a RGB colour mixer here using the inheritance design, it have 3 classes, RedScrollBar, GreenScrollBar and BlueScrollBar. I tried to create a parent class first, called ScrollBar and tried to extend it to 3 classes. But then i realised for each class, i would need to change their variable names too, for example:

```
class BlueScrollBar {
  //establish line x1 y1 and x2 y2
  float blueLX1;
  float blueLY1;
  float blueLX2;
  float blueLY2;

  //establish the box, x, y, width and height;
  float blueBX;
  float blueBY;
  float bW = 20;
  float bH = 20;

  boolean blueMouseOver = false;
  boolean blueBoxLocked = false;

  float blueYOffset = 0.0;

  BlueScrollBar(int lx1, int ly1, int lx2, int ly2) {
    blueLX1 = lx1;
    blueLY1 = ly1;
    blueLX2 = lx2;
    blueLY2 = ly2;

    blueBX = lx1;    
    blueBY = ly2/2;
    }

   void draw(){
    if(mouseX >=blueBX-bW/2 && mouseX <=blueBX+bW/2 && mouseY >=blueBY-bH/2  && mouseY <=blueBY+bH/2 ){
      fill(0);
      blueMouseOver = true;
    } else {
      fill(255);
      blueMouseOver = false;
    }

    line(blueLX1, blueLY1, blueLX2, blueLY2);
    rect(blueBX, blueBY, bW, bH);

    if (blueBY <= blueLY1 || blueBY >= blueLY2) {
      blueBoxLocked = false;
    }

  }

  void mousePressed(){
    if(blueMouseOver){
      blueBoxLocked = true;
      blueBY = mouseY - blueYOffset;
    } else {
      blueBoxLocked = false;
    }
  }

  void mouseDragged(){
    if(blueBoxLocked){
      blueBY = mouseY - blueYOffset;
    }
  }

  void mouseReleased(){
    blueBoxLocked = false;
  }
}
```

and for the RedScrollBar or GreenScrollBar, i could literally copy paste the same code to create a new class but i need to change all the variable that contains the word 'blue' to 'red' or 'green' for it to work. What's a better way to do it? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The variable names don't matter in a class. You could create a BlueScrollBar that's red if you wanted. If you need to pass in a hex color code, that's fine too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were on the right track to start! Make a class named Scrollbar and have the color be set in the constructor of the class (through an enum if you only want to select from a certain set of colors). That way you have one class to solve your problem.

I assume you know how to make a constructor, but if you don't comment on this answer and I will show you.

Edit 1:

Ok, so when you create a class in java a constructor (a fancy name for the function used to create an object of the class) is generated for you if you do not explicitly define one. Whenever you call MyClass test = new MyClass();  chances are you are just using the constructor that is auto generated (no arguments need to be passed to it.)

However, you are going to need your own custom constructor so you would do something like this.

```
public class ScrollBar{
    Color color;
    //your constructor.
    public ScrollBar(Color c){
        this.color = c;
    }
}
```

That being said I'm no sure how you are implementing the color or what framework you are working in so take the code above with a grain of salt.

Note that if you create your own constructor, the default one will not be generated for you. So this would give you an error:

```
ScrollBar test = new ScrollBar(); // :( error
ScrollBar test = new ScrollBar(RED); // :) good
```

Edit 2:

Sorry to mislead you in that way. I was trying to keep my code above very general since I am not sure how you were dealing with color in your program. However you were trying to implement the red/blue/green will work with this method. If you truly only want the three colors you listed, you could just pass an integer to your constructor where 0,1,2 correspond to a specific color you want to use.

ie)

```
public class ScrollBar{

    int c = 0; //default to red if the user gives a bad value

    public ScrollBar(int c){
        if(c >=0 && c <=2){ //check bounds
            this.color = c;
        }
    }

    public setColor(){
        if(this.color == 0){
            //do something with red
        }
        else if(this.color == 1){
            //do something with blue
        }
        else{
            //do something with green
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Andrew, it would very helpful if you show me how you would create the constructor

Comment: Thank you so much Andrew. So this means i would have to create my custom data type Color? Also how would i access variables with similar names this way? i still would like to create 3 classess, but extend them rather then create one class and do everything from it. I've added some code to my question hope that helps, also i'm doing this in processing

Comment: @user3620442 Find generic variable names that fits all. Do not use `blueVariable` or `redVariable`...